# Why should i (not) use the "use" keyword for namespaces

Tags: php, namespaces

I've been working with PHP 5.3 for more than a year now, and there's something I always do that I'm not sure is correct : whenever I use a class outside of the current context's namespace, is use the `use` keyword :

```
use Another\Class
```

so in the code I can write directly :

```
$object = new Class();
```

That's fine, but I often end up with a lot of `use` directives at the beginning of my files, and that's not so nice to maintain (if I don't use this class, I'm not likely to remove the `use` directive).

I could also write the whole namespace each time I use this class :

```
$object = new \Another\Class();
```

So I was wondering two things :

- Is there any drawback of not using the `use` keyword (except the fact that you have to write the whole namespace each time), like things you can't do ?
- Is there any drawback of using it ? (is it even slightly less performant because it somehow imports the class) ?

**Edit**
Just to clarify : I know clean code is more important than small performance tweaks, I just like to know when the computer is working, I like to feel the efforts :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First thing that comes in my mind is the ability to use aliases like:

```
use My\Full\Classname as Another;
```

source [php manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php)

Comment: Taking this approach enables you to write clearer code. "Another" might explain the purpose of the used class better than it's original name because the context might be different.

Answer (score 7):

The one big drawback to *not* using `use`, is the need to type out the full name every time.

The one big drawback to *using* it, is the possibility of name collisions with classes that are already defined.  I'm not sure how PHP handles that, but either way you end up with a little extra hassle.  The plus is that you don't actually have to use the same name...but then, the minus to that is that you have classes that don't correspond to filenames.

Before we even get into more of this performance BS, though:  **If you care about the performance cost of aliasing a freaking *name*, you're doing it wrong.**  Do not worry about "faster" syntax.  Period.  You, your users, and that guy compulsively clicking "Reload" with a stopwatch in hand, will not notice the difference.  *Ever.*  There are far better things to optimize, and that's assuming you've reached the point where you need to.

Comment: It's not wrong to care of the cost of whatever. It **may** be wrong to aim performances over performance rather than readability. I like to know when the computer does something. For ex a method call "costs" but comments don't. I still avoid comments when I can and I add one-line "clarification" methods though. I want to know because I understand a bit better how it works, not because I want to improve performances blindly (or at all). I've clarified the purpose in my question.

Comment: @Julien the point here is that "[nobody] will ... notice the difference[, ever]."

Comment: @JanDvorak : I know, I'm not going to change it, it's just for my technical culture :-)

Comment: @Julien note that if you assume this could be a performance hit, note that declaring unused fields and methods adds overhead too.

Comment: cHao : The "possibility of name collisions with classes that are already" can be avoided by what @Udan mentionned right ? (use My\Full\Classname as Another;) Or maybe I misunderstood this point, which is more what I was looking for actually

Comment: @Julien: Yep.  That's what i meant by "you don't actually have to use the same name".

Comment: @Julien:  As for caring about the cost...my point is, when you're optimizing, you want bang for your buck. **Optimize where it matters; ignore where it doesn't.**  It's common for PHP noobs to care about wacky stuff like replacing all their `"a"`s with `'a'`s, etc.  But in general, syntax comes dead last on the list of stuff to worry about. And in this particular case, it matters once per request (unless you use APC or something, in which case maybe once every *thousand* requests!), and barely blips even then if at all.  *Fix your algorithm*; that's where 99.9% of the CPU's time will be spent.

Comment: Funny, nobody seems to understand that I wasn't going to optimize it, but **I just want to know**... I know that caching compiled files, files in the browser cache, minifying resources are where you gain performances. I know that pre-optimization is evil enough that I think I could teach it. Anyways, I must have been unclear with my purpose, here are some keywords of what I wanted : "knowledge", "culture", "understanding", "feeling the work". And here is not what I want : "micro-optimization", "ugly code",... That's more clear ?

Comment: @Julien: Your mentions of performance just hit a nerve. I have dealt with ricers who would look at this question, see a mention of a possible .001% speed hit, and be like "OMG `use` is so *sllooowww*!". These are the same idjits who'll delete comments and spaces from their code so PHP won't parse as much. I have a very low tolerance for that brand of idiocy, and try to stop it before it starts. Please, if you learn anything culturewise, let it be that ricers are noobs.  Correctness > maintainability > all else > elegance <=> *algorithmic* efficiency >>>> *syntactic* efficiency, IMNSHO.

Comment: So, how would you know "what not to optimize" if you don't know how long stuff actually takes? He asked a clear question. Also, if you have 1ms or  differences that are not noticable, the performance should be counted against millions of calls, not one single call. Also If you lose 1 ms here 1 ms there throughout a script you might end up with 50-100 ms by the end of the script.

Comment: @Sneak: "What not to optimize" isn't even close to the right question. The answer basically is "98% of all the code you will have written throughout your life". You need to know what **to** optimize, cause that's the part that'll pay off. Profile the code, see what's eating up the most time, and start there. Otherwise it's easy to spend more time agonizing over how to save a CPU cycle here or there than you will gain back in the entire lifetime of the application. We're not even talking about milliseconds. We're talking about microseconds on the high side, and perhaps even *zero* on the lower.

Comment: @cHao I agree with you m8. I think you misunderstood me, my point was, unless you ask the question you wouldn't know that you are wasting your time on 98% of the stuff. He asked and you answered :) will give you a vote up for good tips.

Comment: @Sneak: One does have to ask eventually, i guess. But it's far more productive, in general, to start without the paranoia that your tools are conspiring against you. :)  If they are, that will end up revealing itself in the measurements.

Comment: @cHao yeah, true that =)

Answer (score 1):

Namespaces are not backward compatible with PHP < 5.3 you will have to remove all cases of `namespace` and `use` statements if you come across a compatibility issue.

Comment: PHP 5.2 support ended more than 2 years ago. Compatibility shouldn't be an issue, just upgrade PHP. You'll get better performance for free. http://www.php.net/archive/2010.php#id2010-12-16-1

Answer (score 0):

I use Eclipse with PDT and the capability of Eclipse to complete syntax, both using use or complete namespace, make it easy.

Personally, I use "use" most the time (that Eclipse creates automatically when you use autocomplete of classnames), because make a cleaner syntax on the code.

I use a ClassLoader too, and my project use folders in the same order than namespace, so my classloader loads directly each class. I don't need any "include" instruction.

I always use classes (with fex exceptions), even for normal code, where normally i use static code (without instances), because it makes very easy to Eclipse to recognice each class, methos, variable and associated type.

So my code is a lot of files, without global variables, and separated modules on classes so class name collision is rare. And in this few cases, where is easy with Eclipse to detect, I use the complete syntax, or abbreviates (manually, I use an alias of the namespace so I use "namespace_alias\classname" syntax, that is cleaner but don't make collisions).

Use namespace and files that use the same structure and a classloader that search in this way (and adds all paths on include_path directory) has been very productive on large projects.

For example... \Example\Name\Space\Myclass search as

for each listoffolders (root of the project + all in include_path except ".")
 On the start folder -> folder (Example) -> Folder (Name) -> Folder (Space) -> File (Myclass.inc or Myclass.php or Myclass.php5)
endfor

Answer (score 0):

The usage of `use` keyword does not trigger import (autoload) of the class until it is being used (according to answer in https://stackoverflow.com/a/35755296/5189780)

So, it should not impact performance.

Other arguments such as running under php 5.3 relates more to decision to use *namespaces* or not. Since PHP does not yet provide real possibility to encapsulate classes inside namespaces (restrict access), usage of it just helps to have more clear code and resolve naming conflicts. Without usage of `use` keyword, you cannot really benefit from namespaces.

According to php documentation:

> In the PHP world, namespaces are designed to solve two problems that authors of libraries and applications encounter when creating re-usable code elements such as classes or functions:
>
> 1. Name collisions between code you create, and internal PHP classes/functions/constants or third-party classes/functions/constants.
>      Ability to alias (or shorten) Extra_Long_Names designed to alleviate the first problem, improving readability of source code.
> 2. If you are using namespaces, import them with `use` keyword and it will make code more clear and organized.