# Does the 'use' keyword trigger autoloading in PHP?

Tags: php, autoload

In the example below, at what point does the autoloader load the class file, if at all? For example, if `$boolean_test === false` does the Subpackage get loaded?

```php
use Org\Group\Package\Subpackage; // autoloader triggered here?
if ($boolean_test) {
    Subpackage::method(); // or here?
}
```

I prefer the `use` statement near the top of the code so I can see what packages are used in the page and for slightly better readability. But, if packages are only used based on conditionals, I may be loading unneeded resources.

Comment: A simple echo in your subpackage.php would reveal the answere

Comment: while it's a easy question to test and answer, the docs leave it totally unclear.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No `use` does not trigger autoloading. You can have an invalid `use` at the top of your file and PHP won't complain.

Autoloading happens when you attempt to use the class.

It's quite easy to test this: https://3v4l.org/OccF3